# I'm trying to make reaction roles using my own discord bot but for some reason it doesn't add the role even though it adds the reactions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot that adds roles from reactions. I've been following a tutorial from CodeLyon and I hit a snag and I cant find a fix

Basically, I got the bot to send a embed message and it adds the reactions to the message. But it doesn't add the roles.

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "reactionrole",
  description: "Sets up a reaction role message!",
  async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
    const channel = "907732565685846036";
    const ACRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(
      (role) => role.name === "Animal Crossing"
    );

    const ACEmoji = "";

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("#e42643")
      .setTitle("Choose which games you play!")
      .setDescription(
        "React to add the games you play as a role (and receive pings)\n\n" +
          `${ACEmoji} for Animal Crossing\n`
      );

    let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    messageEmbed.react(ACEmoji);

    client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {
      if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
      if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
      if (user.bot) return;
      if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

      if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === ACEmoji) {
          await reaction.message.guild.members.cache
            .get(user.id)
            .roles.add(ACRole);
        }
      } else {
        return;
      }
    });

    client.on("messageReactionRemove", async (reaction, user) => {
      if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
      if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
      if (user.bot) return;
      if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

      if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === ACEmoji) {
          await reaction.message.guild.members.cache
            .get(user.id)
            .roles.remove(ACRole);
        }
      } else {
        return;
      }
    });
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my main.js (some people use index.js) file I had to change `const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ['GUILDS', 'GUILD_MESSAGES', 'GUILD_MESSAGE'] }, { partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION" ] })`

to

`const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ['GUILDS', 'GUILD_MESSAGES', 'GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS'] }, { partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION" ] })`

It fixed it for a little bit but it randomly stopped working again.